# Clustering correlated variables based on correlation matrix

Tags: correlation, clustering, python, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I'm trying to group correlated variables together. I calculated the correlation matrix (Pearson correlation) and filtered out insignificantly correlated variables.

What I'm left with is this correlation matrix (Python):

```
corr = np.asarray([[ 1.        , -0.0203017 ,  0.01597614, -0.08606197, -0.26817918,
                    -0.83517218,  0.00232017,  0.02080507, -0.04197305,  0.24193934,
                     0.55975631, -0.02848723,  0.11169831],
                   [-0.0203017 ,  1.        , -0.28871367,  0.07712827, -0.01872119,
                     0.00968394, -0.84190025,  0.29734194, -0.03691375, -0.05163921,
                     0.14567088,  0.31608445,  0.0089805 ],
                   [ 0.01597614, -0.28871367,  1.        ,  0.06309928, -0.0771897 ,
                     0.12276402,  0.23658969, -0.97003472, -0.04034719,  0.08949067,
                     0.10113853, -0.12953224,  0.07544441],
                   [-0.08606197,  0.07712827,  0.06309928,  1.        , -0.10443245,
                     0.1253936 , -0.04070633, -0.09509433, -0.82558084, -0.02611453,
                    -0.14586145,  0.20172068, -0.02510469],
                   [-0.26817918, -0.01872119, -0.0771897 , -0.10443245,  1.        ,
                     0.14518334, -0.01315547,  0.07084393,  0.13159619, -0.90127075,
                    -0.18569184, -0.05251947, -0.03355281],
                   [-0.83517218,  0.00968394,  0.12276402,  0.1253936 ,  0.14518334,
                     1.        ,  0.01061786, -0.14152792, -0.03568505, -0.11042734,
                    -0.34177675, -0.00435837, -0.03484822],
                   [ 0.00232017, -0.84190025,  0.23658969, -0.04070633, -0.01315547,
                     0.01061786,  1.        , -0.29191501, -0.03756422,  0.04060199,
                    -0.11910248, -0.11876712, -0.00102932],
                   [ 0.02080507,  0.29734194, -0.97003472, -0.09509433,  0.07084393,
                    -0.14152792, -0.29191501,  1.        ,  0.07295001, -0.05938729,
                    -0.04002804,  0.10546885, -0.03885392],
                   [-0.04197305, -0.03691375, -0.04034719, -0.82558084,  0.13159619,
                    -0.03568505, -0.03756422,  0.07295001,  1.        , -0.05371411,
                     0.12649711, -0.08835831,  0.04666688],
                   [ 0.24193934, -0.05163921,  0.08949067, -0.02611453, -0.90127075,
                    -0.11042734,  0.04060199, -0.05938729, -0.05371411,  1.        ,
                     0.21243162, -0.03047389,  0.0456781 ],
                   [ 0.55975631,  0.14567088,  0.10113853, -0.14586145, -0.18569184,
                    -0.34177675, -0.11910248, -0.04002804,  0.12649711,  0.21243162,
                     1.        , -0.01588074,  0.17283502],
                   [-0.02848723,  0.31608445, -0.12953224,  0.20172068, -0.05251947,
                    -0.00435837, -0.11876712,  0.10546885, -0.08835831, -0.03047389,
                    -0.01588074,  1.        , -0.005598  ],
                   [ 0.11169831,  0.0089805 ,  0.07544441, -0.02510469, -0.03355281,
                    -0.03484822, -0.00102932, -0.03885392,  0.04666688,  0.0456781 ,
                     0.17283502, -0.005598  ,  1.        ]])
```

which I can plot as a heat map (red patches, are positively correlated, blue ones negatively):

[image]

Ideally, only positively correlated (red) variables get grouped together (variables that are only negatively correlated to all others should form their own 1-element cluster) and the number of groups (or clusters) should be small. I found [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/papers/corrclusteringFOCS.pdf) paper on correlation cluster by Bansal, Blum and Chawla, but as far as I understand it, they are only considering positive and negative correlations (not the degree of correlation).

At this point, I just need an algorithm to get me going; one that's "easy" to implement, published/referenceable (would be nice). I don't care about run-time performance or complexity too much, as at the moment I am only dealing with less than 20 variables.

**Update**

I took @ttnphns advice and used a hierarchical clustering algorithm to cluster by correlation (I believe the algorithm is using a distance metric of 1-Pearson correlation). I obtained a dendrogram as follows (actual Pearson correlation showing at the red dots):

[image]

which makes sense when comparing heat map with the dendrogram. For instance variable 0 and 10 have the highest correlation (darkest red); then variable 9 should be added to the cluster (next highest correlation with the 0 and 9).

Comment: `and filtered out insignificantly correlated variables` Why did you do that?

Comment: For any square symmetric (dis)similarity matrix of not huge size, hierarchical clustering is one of the best approaches. You might want to choose complete linkage in it.

Comment: Great comment - this helped a lot to get me looking into the right direction. From the dendrogram, I can use those clusters with distance < 1.0 to form clusters of correlated variables.

Comment: I've seen affinity propagation algorithm used in this setting, but I haven't used it myself. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ea78/2c8b0848987e9575ea648e0419054d3f5bbf.pdf

Comment: If you add your code that would be helpful for others. Also if your update answered your question, you could post it as an answer to your own question and accept it as the answer. Then it is easier for others to find your answer.